# Last system call from a process in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I need to obtain the last system call from a process in a bash script only if I have permission to read. I'm doing this:

```
# $pid is the pid from the process
cat /proc/$pid/syscall
```

But when I do this, I get this message:

```
cat: /proc/21/syscall: Permission denied
```

or this one:

```
cat: /proc/2101/syscall: Operation not permitted
```

is this right? obviously permissions denied means i can't read it. But what does "Operation not permitted" mean?

And from one process, I get this line:

```
0 0x3 0x717000 0x10000 0x7ffca5422b00 0x0 0x79 0x7ffca5422c50 0x7f840be43810
```

Which one is the last system call?

Comment: For "Permission denied": try running as root or with `sudo`?

Comment: Operation not permitted is the problem. Permission denied means i can't read it so that's ok, but what means Operation not permitted ?

Answer (score 3):

About `Operation not permitted`, it is because you have read access to the file (the process is owned by you), but the kernel prohibits you to do so.

If you run `dmesg` after that error appears, you will see the following line:

```
ptrace of pid 12304 was attempted by: cat (pid 12342)
```

That is because the kernel avoids tracing a process that is not a child of the current one. This is controlled via the `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope` configuration option. If you do

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

it will have a value of 1.

More info: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Roadmap/KernelHardening#ptrace

Comment: use `sudo`, or disable the protection using `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`. To make that permanent across reboots, see if you have the file `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf` and set it also to 0.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `strace`:

```
$ strace -o /tmp/out command args; tail -n 2 /tmp/out
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```